# how to identify the priority range in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The nice command is used to set the priority of the process. I want to know what is the priority range in my system? How can I identify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of priorities supported by the `nice` utility is always `-20` (highest) to `20` (lowest).

Comment: What about real-time priorities if the kernel is compiled with CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT?

Answer (score 2):

In the standard Linux kernel, real-time priorities range from zero to (MAX_RT_PRIO-1), inclusive. By default, MAX_RT_PRIO is 100. Non-real-time tasks have priorities in the range of MAX_RT_PRIO to (MAX_RT_PRIO + 40). This constitutes the nice values of SCHED_NORMAL tasks. By default, the –20 to 19 nice range maps directly onto the priority range of 100 to 139.

Process priority values range from -20 to 19.

A process with the nice value of -20 is considered to be on top of the priority. And a process with nice value of 19 is considered to be low on the priority list.

rt.h includes following

```
 #define MAX_USER_RT_PRIO        100
 #define MAX_RT_PRIO             MAX_USER_RT_PRIO

 #define MAX_PRIO                (MAX_RT_PRIO + 40)
 #define DEFAULT_PRIO            (MAX_RT_PRIO + 20)
```

source -http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/real-time-linux-kernel-scheduler
           http://www.slashroot.in/nice-and-renice-command-usage-examples-process-priority-linux

Comment: This does not answer the OP question. The OP asked how can he find these numbers on his system. You need to ammend your answer to say that to find these numbers you need to find which kernel version you are running and whether it is compiled with CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT/CONFIG_RT or not, then download the source for that version of the kernel and check the numbers in the source code. There is no way to find these numbers from userspace.

Comment: Also, you've plagiarized all of the text of this answer from a variety of sources, including http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/real-time-linux-kernel-scheduler and http://www.slashroot.in/nice-and-renice-command-usage-examples-process-priority-linux

Comment: @duskwuff That's a serious allegation. I wouldn't go that far. Almost every answer on thie site has roots in some some man page or article and this answer seems to be an amalgam. The most I would ask is maybe to add some links to the sources.

Comment: @Jonathan Ben-Avraham: An amalgam of plagiarized content is still plagiarized content. On our site, it's considered plagiarism if links to sources are missing, because the post bears the post author's name and not the original author of the text that was copied. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do